# How to switch from nvidia to nouveau drivers on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, nouveau

Running ubuntu 18.04 with nvidia-driver-390. How can I switch to nouveau and make the change persistent between reboots?

Answer (score 21):

You can switch drivers by running the GUI **Additional Drivers** from the **Software and Update** app.

Or you can do it from the terminal commandline by running these commands:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
```

This will show you your available drivers.  Then pick the nouveau driver found and switch to it with this command:

```
$ sudo apt install [xserver-xorg-video-nouveau]
```

The `[xserver-xorg-video-nouveau]` is an example a nouveau driver that might be found.

If for some reason you have removed your nouveau drivers, you can reinstall them with (for example):

```
$ sudo apt install nouveau-firmware
```

You can verify the available nouveau drivers from the repository with this command:

```
$ apt search nouveau
```

Comment: I cannot find any explanation of what `nouveau-firmware` is needed for exactly.  It is not listed among dependencies of `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`, and selecting `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` with GUI Driver Manager does not install `nouveau-firmware`.  Could it be useful to install `nouveau-firmware` manually?  Does the Nvidia card model matter?

Comment: You may be right that the particular driver may not be needed.  The command lines (which I edited the answer to clarify) are intended as examples for installing drivers.

Comment: When I try to install `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` it says: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-video-nouveau : Depends: xorg-video-abi-23
                              Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.18.99.901)

Comment: That means your library configuration is broken.  There are quite a few Q&A's that addresses fixing **unmet dependencies** issues.  This is a carefully filtered Google search of this site that may help you get started: 
https://www.google.com/search?ei=wcsbXc2ZNoK0gge4lpiYDg&q=%22ubuntu%22+how+to+resolve+video+unmet+dependencies+site%3Aaskubuntu.com&oq=%22ubuntu%22+how+to+resolve+video+unmet+dependencies+site%3Aaskubuntu.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71l8.0.0..307347...0.0..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.b9VnL4hfPcE
 The first one (currently) on the list will likely resolve your issue.

Answer (score 8):

Run

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-driver-390
sudo apt autoremove
```

and reboot.

Another way is to do it in "Software & Updates" -> Additional Drivers tab.

Comment: I've tried that but then when rebooting it doesn't enter to desktop.

Comment: That may mean that your video card is not perfectly supported by nouveau.

Answer (score 1):

Answer my own question: ubuntu-drivers and "Software and Update > Additional drivers" are broken on ubuntu 18.04. We'll have to wait until developers fix it. For now just use the proprietary nvidia driver which works ok.

Answer (score 1):

On Xubuntu 18.04, "Software and Update > Additional drivers" worked for me, but I had to replace the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file by the original one, /etc/X11/xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original, which in my case is just a blank file.