# Laptop won't wake up after suspend

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend

I have a laptop HP Spectre x360 with an Nvidia GeForce MX150. Yesterday I did a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 install and almost everything worked just fine. The only issue that I have is that when I suspend the laptop, when I want to use it again I only get a black screen with this message:

`[187.425322] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 32, Channel ID 00000000 intr 800400000`

After that, I can't do anything. Just force shutdown and restart again. What can it be? I'm using the proprietary drivers (nvidia-driver-390).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I was able to fix it by updating the kernel to the version 4.18 with the **Ukuu** app. Beware, the kernel version 4.17 doesn't fix the problem.

You can get the **Ukuu** app via [this link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/02/ukuu-install-latest-kernels-ubuntu-linux-mint/)

Comment: Were you able to use the proprietary Nvidia drivers after updating the kernel to 4.18 with Ukuu?

Answer (score 1):

If anybody else is having the same issue, the solution seems to be on kernel 4.17. According to the Nvidia documentation, this type of event (meaning event 32)

> ...is logged when a fault is reported by the DMA controller which
>   manages the communication stream between the NVIDIA driver and the GPU
>   over the PCI-E bus. These failures primarily involve quality issues on
>   PCI, and are generally not caused by user application actions.

In this case and according to the logs, the GPU (GeForce MX150) fails to power on after suspend and that would be an ACPI bug in the kernel. According to other users, this issue with this specific GPU is solved if kernel 4.17 is installed. In my case I prefer to wait until that, or a superior version is pushed for Ubuntu 18.04. If everything goes as usual, it is posible that Ubuntu 18.04.1 will come with the same kernel of Ubuntu 18.04 (4.15). And is also posible that Ubuntu 18.10 will come with kernel 4.18 or superior. In that case, Ubuntu 18.04.2 will also come with that kernel version. So it is probably going to be next year (February?) that we have a solution for this issue. Meanwhile you can use the Nouveau drivers or manually update de kernel to 4.17. I'm not sure if that is recommended or not.

Answer (score 0):

Had a same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 with nvidia geforce gtx 1650.
Solved it by changing graphics driver from nouveau(Open-Source) to Proprietary nvidia-driver-470 (might vary in your case).
Here's how to do it:

1. open software & updates from applications menu
2. go to Additional drivers
3. Select appropriate driver. (For me, proprietary and tested worked)
4. Apply changes and reboot

If somehow you selected wrong driver, refer to [How to switch from nvidia to nouveau drivers on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032357/how-to-switch-from-nvidia-to-nouveau-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04) to switch back to correct driver in recovery.