# Ubuntu 18.10 laptop does not wake up after about 20-30 minutes of unuse time

Tags: suspend, wakeup, 18.10

I was doing some work on the Thinkpad X1 Extreme with 18.10 installed. Then I went to watch TV. About 20-30 minutes later, when I got back to the laptop, the screen was black. Pressing any key on the keyboard does not lead to any respond from the laptop. Pressing the power button led to the light on the button blinking. What does that mean? The only way to get back to the system is to force reboot. Is this a bug?

Comment: Try this
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053008/laptop-wont-wake-up-after-suspend

Comment: Seems like a crash (maybe caused by a bug, maybe not). Check your /var/log/syslog for the time around sleep and non-wakeup for clues..

Comment: Some errors include: failed to set new screen percentage, screen backlight not available, Disabled Secure Boot in Bios and reinstalled 18.10. Issue remains. Sill can’t wake from suspend.

Comment: I hear fan noise so perhaps the machine is not sleeping but the screen is just black. To test, I connected to an external 4KTV. I saw background wallpaper of login screen with no login prompt. I just typed the password and the 4KTV background changed to the wallpaper I set for th normal desktop. So it seems that the problem is the laptop screen failed to turn on. Know how to fix this? Perhaps this is related to the issue that I cannot change screen brightness using function keys.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem! If I wake the system soon after sleep, no problem, after about half an hour, just the black screen. I do not have an nvidia card. My syslog from the point of suspend-awake is at https://gist.github.com/1f67e0e8f488f15f5aa66c04634d4a40 -- maybe that has some clues for people who know how to read these.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with my desktop.

I can restart the session doing one of two things:

- suspend (not restart) and then immediately resume or switch to another screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>FnKey</kbd>
- and then back to my graphical screen (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> in my case).

These two actions seems to restart the login interface and I can get back to the session.