# Screen garbage after resuming from suspend

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, suspend

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on a laptop. When I close the lid and then open it, the screen turns on but displays the garbage shown in the attached pictures taken with my phone. Does anyone know how to fix this?

For what it's worth, the laptop has an nVidia GTX 1060 GPU and `ubuntu-drivers list` shows that I have `nvidia-driver-410` installed.

**Update** I discovered that running `prime-select intel` to use Intel graphics fixes the problem, so the issue only seems to happen when using nVidia graphics (`prime-select nvidia`.)

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is a known Nvidia bug. As far as I know, any combination of the proprietary Nvidia driver version & video card are affected.
You could probably eliminate the issue by switching to the free driver (nouveau), but then you would lose the added performance. Look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032357/how-to-switch-from-nvidia-to-nouveau-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04) for switching to nouveau. Also some workarounds from [this topic](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/kde-nvidia-screen-corruption-after-resume/60064/23) may be helpful.

Comment: Related for Chromium: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273399/problems-with-chrome-browser-after-suspend-the-computer-on-ubuntu-20-04