# Problems with Chrome browser after suspending the computer on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, suspend, google-chrome, plasma-5

- Kubuntu 20.04, 64 bit
- GPU: Geforce GT610
- nvidia-driver-390
- Chrome Version 85.0.4183.83
- Intel i5-4430, core 4, 4 thread , 3GHz
- RAM: 16GB

Each time I go into suspend mode and then resume, Chrome browser displays the current tab as full of sand of colors, something like dithering in image processing.

[image: screenshot]

Other tabs display glitches too.

The current solution is to close and reopen the browser.

I tested `nvidia-driver-418` but got a black screen problem and reinstalled `nvidia-driver-390`.

The problem is more evident in Chrome, but it sometimes appears in vscode in small areas. There, hovering the mouse over the affected place or resizing the window fixes the problem. In Kubuntu the avatar of the user in the application launcher also shows dithered.

[image: screenshot]

I tested in the same machine with fedora 32 workstation(gnome), nvidia driver, and had the same problems with Chrome browser.

[image: ubuntu-drivers output]

Could it be a GPU problem?

Comment: Could you see if the solution from https://askubuntu.com/q/1270689 helps?

Comment: Me too, I created a bookmark for chrome://restart so can click it whenever the machine wakes up. Had a new version of Chrome today but it still doing it.
I am plain old 20.04 Ubuntu runing on a Dell XPS 17 2020

Comment: Same issue on Ubuntu 20.04.01 on ThinkPad W530. The answer below solved it!

Comment: This has come in with a recent update, as I had no issues before. I am also seeing issues with kdiff3. Not noticed any issues with VSCode myself, but maybe they are too subtle from me to of noticed yet.

Running a Dell XPS 15 with 20.04.

Comment: I just wanted to add that the reason that VSCode experiences issues is because it runs on ElectronJS which further runs on Chromium. As far as I know, FireFox does not experience these problems. Thus, it's an underlying problem in Chromium. I've only had success solving the problem by disabling hardware acceleration although this is not ideal. I think the best course of action is to wait for the problem to be patched at Chromium.

Comment: Happens on `19.10` as well. Chrome version: `85.0.4183.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)`. It started happening after upgrading chrome.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270689/chrome-causing-weird-flickering-since-upgrade-to-85-0-4183-83

Comment: Upstream bug: [bugs.chromium.org #1113040](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1113040)

Comment: I just upgraded from 20.04 to 20.10 and this issue began. Very annoying as I use the suspend and restore from suspend throughout the day. I have no idea what NVIDIA driver I had before the upgrade, but now it brought me up to Nvidia-driver-450. I manually upgraded to Nvidia-driver-455 hoping that would resolve the issue but no such luck. I'll try adding the Chrome flag. Probably should have stuck with the LTS release!

Comment: There is no  problem in fedora 33 with Nouveau NVD9 open source drivers, it would be very important to test if the problem persist with nouveau in ubuntu.

Comment: It seems so many people like me have the same problem. At the moment, the best solution is  `chrome://restart/`

Comment: The issue is fixed for me on `nvidia-driver-455` and Chrome `Version 87.0.4280.66 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: There is a similar issue in Chrome's bug tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1134981

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I'm having more or less the same issue, on:

- Ubuntu 18.04, 64 bit
- GPU: GeForce GTX 1070
- Driver: 440.100
- Chrome Version: 86.0.4240.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I don't want to have to deactivate GPU usage for Chrome, and I don't want to have to restart the browser every time, losing all my tabs.

But I found a workaround that is good enough for me (at least for now):

### You can kill just the browser's GPU process

- Open the Task Manager:

  - Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (as pointed out by [@NYCeyes in the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273399/problems-with-chrome-browser-after-suspending-the-computer-on-ubuntu-20-04#comment2179489_1283817)).
  - Or alternatively, go to the Chrome main menu (3 dots on the top right corner) → *More Tools* → *Task Manager*.
- Sort by process *Task* name.
- Find the process called *GPU Process*.
- Click on <kbd>End process</kbd>.

[image: Chrome Task Manager - GPU Process - End process]

That will "clean" all the glitchy image noise. And Chrome will immediately create a new GPU process automatically.

**Note**: You can automatize the process, check [Andrew Bruce's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273399/problems-with-chrome-browser-after-suspending-the-computer-on-ubuntu-20-04/1289285#1289285) putting these steps in a script that runs automatically.

I assume the problem is something like the GPU process using memory assuming it has the old state as before the sleep cycle, but it just has some default random noise from the default state. So I imagine Ubuntu doesn't save and restore GPU memory on a sleep cycle (I don't think it should) but the Chrome process doesn't detect that. And by killing the process it "frees" that GPU memory and then Chrome creates a new process that re-generates any needed GPU memory state (that's instant).

Comment: \o/ This is an excellent answer and works without making performance compromises. I will note though, that because Chrome's hamburger menu may be obfuscated by the glitchy pixelation, simply pressing `<Shift>` + `<Escape>` will get you to Chrome's (and Chromium's) `Task Manager` directly, where you can then kill the `GPU process` that you mentioned.

Comment: This is the best answer so far.

Comment: This is also exactly why linux is currently not really suitable as a daily driver. I have this issue every time and it's soo annoying. Still, linux/unix is 100x better than windows when developing so I guess I'm stuck with this mess.

Comment: Thanks pal, very useful solution. think that the problem is with NVIDIA drivers and the kernel in Linux, because in fedora 33 with open source drivers nouveau there is no problems about it, but after install NVIDIA proprietary drivers from rpmfusion in fedora 33 the problems begin to appears.

Comment: And the problems appears in vscode too, in kubuntu it affects to the user avatar.

Comment: This answer, combined with [Andrew Bruce's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1289285/618353), is the best option to use Chromium-based browsers with hardware acceleration until the problem gets resolved.

Comment: This works, but has its own side effects. After a few rounds of suspend-restart-suspend-restart, Chrome detects the successive failures and reverts back to software emulation. Everything will work and the GPU process will even show up under Chrome Task Manager, but if you investigate with `chrome://gpu/` you'll see that you're running in software emulation, which uses your CPU instead of GPU. Unfortunately the only real clean solution I found so far is to restart Chrome entirely (which is a pain).

Comment: Similar issue in Chrome's bug tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1134981

Answer (score 82):

Same problem for me.

Enabling `enable-vulkan` in `chrome://flags` then restarting the browser fixed it. If that does not work, you can also try enabling `ignore-gpu-blacklist` as well.

<sub>Answer based on [this old askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1272506/333907)
answer</sub>

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!!!

Comment: This slows down dramatically chrome with 10+ open tabs...

Comment: No need to enable ignore-gpu-blacklist. Just enabling Vulkan fixes the issue for me, although chrome does get slow down, especially when multiple windows are open :(

Comment: Just enabling Vulkan fixed it for me.

Comment: It fixed the issue. but make chrome really slow when watching youtube.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It fixed the issue for me. My specs: Ubuntu 20.04, Ryzen 7, RTX 2060.

Comment: Fixes the rendering issue, but now the CPU cooler goes full speed all the tiime.

Comment: Fixed the issue for me but not sure about performance. Will edit comment later when I have a large amount of tabs open.

Comment: I had the same issue on my new machine with Ubuntu 20.10 and Chrome "86.0.4240.111 (Official Build) (64-bit)", but this still fixed it!

Comment: Works. Ubuntu 20.04, Nvidia Vulkan β drivers, google-chrome-β. Hole feeling that it start work even faster! At lease is shows 42 fps now, vs 25 fps before on this page: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ldB3Dt

Comment: Enabling Vulkan made my Google Maps crawl like a snail.

Comment: Worked for me too! Ubuntu 20.04 with nVIDIA 480 (proprietary, tested) on a Dell laptop with nVIDIA GTX 1050 Ti Mobile had issue with Google Chrome. If I would take a tab and drag it to be a separate window, that window would be drawn with additive over everything and pretty much be either all white after few seconds. Enabling Vulkan extension fixed it! Thanks mate!

Comment: this chrome bug also bothered my for a while and the `enable-vulkan` setting fixed it! I use Chrome on Xubuntu (20.04 upgraded to 22.04, NVIDIA 2060+Ryzen 4800H) everyday and did not have this issue until Fall 2023 after google-chrome-stable upgraded from 115 to 116 - I reported the issue to Chrome and tested every new release, but nothing changes. I had to revert to v115 to avoid such problem. My new laptop with Intel CPU+NVIDIA 4070 did not have this issue (same xubuntu 22.04).

Comment: works on ubuntu 22 chrome 120.0.6099.199 as well

Answer (score 27):

Using [tiangolo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1283817/618353), you can automate the restart of the Chrome GPU process on wake. As root, I put this script in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/revive-chrome-gpu`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ "$2" = "suspend" ] || [ "$2" = "hybrid-sleep" ]
then
    case "$1" in
        pre)
            true 
            ;;
        post) 
            sleep 1
            pkill -f 'chrome \-\-type=gpu-process'
            ;;
    esac
fi
```

Be sure to make the script executable with:

```
chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/revive-chrome-gpu
```

Comment: This works and is a handy addition to [tiangolo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1283817/618353). Note that if you use another Chromium-based browser, for example Brave, you should properly change the `pkill` command. In Brave's case it would become `pkill -f 'brave --type=gpu-process'`.

Comment: Nice! I used it and it works perfectly. I just added a note to my original answer pointing to this answer. 

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer!
Solves the problem also for Electron-based apps, e.g. my file now has 3 pkill commands like this:
```sh
pkill -f 'chrome \-\-type=gpu-process'; pkill -f 'keycombiner \-\-type=gpu-process'; pkill -f 'spotify \-\-type=gpu-process'
```

Comment: You're welcome. You could get fancy and use a regexp instead of the three kills. An exercise for the reader!

Comment: For me, I find that just a `pkill -f type=gpu-process` will work for Chrome and other Electron-based apps all in one go. That being said, I have switched Chrome to using Vulkan too.

Comment: I found that this solution doesn't work nicely with xterm.js (VS Code terminal as well as Hyper terminal). It winds up causing most of the terminal to go blank. I wound up having to resize VS Code (`Ctrl +` then `Ctrl -` to solve my problems). With Hyper I have to restart completely.

Comment: Yeah I still end up restarting my browser, because although the image is restored and usable, the scrolling etc. is severely degraded after the GPU process has been killed. Perhaps the processes using the old GPU process are kicked down to CPU?

Comment: I had to use this plus https://askubuntu.com/a/1274056/384952 in my previous setup (Ubuntu 22.04 and using the Nouveau drivers for my RTX 3050). After upgrading to 23.10, I was able to use the proprietary Nvidia drivers (version 535) and this script was no longer needed, only enabling Vulkan as the other answer suggested.

Answer (score 15):

I have the same issues on Arch, and although enabling Vulkan does fix the glitches when resuming from sleep or hibernation, it also impacts performance a lot. Based on [this bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1122224#c14) and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1270843/261198) I've tried starting Chrome with the following flags: `--use-cmd-decoder=validating --use-gl=desktop` and this seems to fix my issue without any performance penalties.

I'm not sure if this applies to all distros, but on Arch you can put these arguments into `~/.config/chrome-flags.conf` and then they will be used every time Chrome is started (or `~/.config/chromium-flags.conf` if [using Chromium](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chromium#Making_flags_persistent)):

**`~/.config/chrome-flags.conf`**

```js
--use-cmd-decoder=validating --use-gl=desktop
```

Comment: This is an Arch-specific extension, and is not currently available in other Linux variants (that I know of).

Comment: Thanks pal, `disabling hardware acceleration` reduce the performance. That's flags works better. You can run chrome by terminal `google-chrome-stable --use-cmd-decoder=validating --use-gl=desktop &`, using  `&` avoid blocking the terminal.

Comment: Upvoted. Starting chrome with `google-chrome --use-gl=desktop` solved the issue. Saw it here as well: https://askubuntu.com/a/1270843/13330

Answer (score 7):

**1<sup>st</sup> Solution (performance issues)**

In my case a solution for the Chrome browser is `disable` in `Settings`: `Use hardware acceleration when available`.

```
chrome://settings/system
```

[image]

**2<sup>nd</sup> Solution**

Yes, the above solution comes with performance issues. If you don't like that, you can test this other option, Chrome will run flawlessly.

Run Chrome with some flags, run always Chrome by terminal.

```
google-chrome-stable --use-cmd-decoder=validating --use-gl=desktop &
```

The `&` avoid blocking the terminal.

Comment: This comes with huge performance penalty, especially when watching videos. If you're on laptop, your batter life will get shortened a lot.

Comment: Has anyone tested the second solution? Can you explain what exactly those flags are doing?

Comment: The second solution worked for me .. Thanks :)

Comment: Disabling hardware acceleration worked for me.

Comment: You can change the shortcut for Chrome to include these parameters, thus you don't need to run it from a terminal.

Answer (score 5):

I followed [xx77aBs's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1275573/288581) but, since I'm using Chromium under Ubuntu, I added these options in `/etc/chromium-browser/customizations`, as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/786390/288581). I added a file named `nvidia-fix` under that directory with the following content:

```
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="${CHROMIUM_FLAGS} --use-cmd-decoder=validating --use-gl=desktop"
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar issue on my **Arch** system with both **Chrome** and **Chromium** where I had to *restart* it ever time after *sleep* (**VS code** and **Steam** also had minor artifact but simply switching tabs fixed it there)

Simply enabling **Vulkan** in `chrome://flags` seems to have finally resolved it.

I also wanted to mention that I did not suffer from this issue up until several weeks ago
I am on **nVidia 1060** with **450.66** driver

Comment: this works for Brave on my Kubuntu 20.04 system, using `brave://flags`, thanks!

Comment: Worked for met too: GTX 1060, driver 455

Answer (score 3):

xx77aBs's can be adapted for Chrome, not Chromium, on Ubuntu using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/78874/265407).

```sh
cp /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop ~ # or wherever you want to keep that desktop launch file
sed -i 's/google-chrome-stable /google-chrome-stable --use-cmd-decoder=validating --use-gl=desktop /' ~/google-chrome.desktop
chmod +x ~/google-chrome.desktop
```

Then use that newly created and modified `.desktop` file to launch Chrome.

Comment: Thanks pal, now in the future when we don't need those flags, how can we revert that?

Comment: You can just stop using the modified `.desktop` file and use the one installed by the package instead when that happens.

Answer (score 2):

For my setup (Ubuntu 20.04, Thinkpad P53) flag `--use-gl=desktop` was enough to avoid Chromium problems after resume. I didn't notice a visible slowdown of my machine.

I added the file `~/.chromium-browser.init` with contents:
`CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--use-gl=desktop"`.

Comment: This seems to be the simplest solution and it works fine on my system for Chromium! (Also an Ubuntu 20.04 system with Intel i5, Nvidia GeForce graphics, recommended Nvidia driver.) However I do also use Chrome (the Google version), does anyone know how to apply this fix for Chrome? I tried ".chrome-browser.init" and "CHROME_FLAGS" but that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this script (works for Ubuntu 20.04), then reboot

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Followed by this tutorial: https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/450.57/README/powermanagement.html

NVIDIA_DRIVER_VERSION=$(head -1 /proc/driver/nvidia/version | sed "s/.*Kernel Module *\([0-9]*\)\. *.*/\1/g")
NVIDIA_DIR=/usr/share/doc/nvidia-driver-${NVIDIA_DRIVER_VERSION}


if [[ ! -d ${NVIDIA_DIR} ]]; then
    echo ${NVIDIA_DIR} does not exist. Skipping.
    exit 0
fi

# Installing
sudo install ${NVIDIA_DIR}/nvidia-suspend.service   /etc/systemd/system
sudo install ${NVIDIA_DIR}/nvidia-hibernate.service /etc/systemd/system
sudo install ${NVIDIA_DIR}/nvidia-resume.service    /etc/systemd/system
sudo install ${NVIDIA_DIR}/nvidia                   /lib/systemd/system-sleep
sudo install ${NVIDIA_DIR}/nvidia-sleep.sh          /usr/bin

# Enabling nvidia systemd
sudo systemctl enable nvidia-suspend.service
sudo systemctl enable nvidia-hibernate.service
sudo systemctl enable nvidia-resume.service
```

UPD1:
for ones, who don't know how to make it as a script

1. create file: `install_nvidia_powermanagement.sh`
2. copy paste the content into `install_nvidia_powermanagement.sh`
3. make it a executable: `chmod +x install_nvidia_powermanagement.sh`
4. run it: `./install_nvidia_powermanagement.sh`

Comment: Do we run with `sudo`?

Comment: No, as you can see: `sudo` is inside the script

Comment: Oh, then u have several drivers. IDK, just change the `NVIDIA_DIR` to the driver path u have installed

Comment: Updated the script to get the right version

Comment: Although I've upvoted, this not solved the issue. The best is `chrome://restart/`

Comment: Sad to hear. Thanks for the upvote. In my case, it solves partially: Slack (which is based on chrome) now works fine, but Firefox is still has "artifacts" after suspending

Comment: I've only problem with the chrome, though, strange.

Answer (score 1):

My problems with chrome after resume were reproducible by switching to vty and back to X or after sleep, lock etc.  I finally ran with the --disable-extensions flag from the command line and the problem went away.

The issue was pretty strange. It would jumble contents from different tabs or block out portions of pages with large black block or leftover content from a previous tab.  Scrolling caused issues too or popover etc.

Via trial and error I narrowed in on ....

[Microsoft Office Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office/ndjpnladcallmjemlbaebfadecfhkepb/related)

It apparently messes with the browsers use of gl. It was spitting out these errors when started from a console and triggering the bug. Disabling or removind the extension fixed it.

```
ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] ClearErrors(2057): Preexisting GL error 0x00000506 as of ../../third_party/angle/src/libANGLE/renderer/gl/TextureGL.cpp, setImageHelper:256.
```

86.0.4240.75 Linux 5.4.0-48-generic nvidia 450 and libnvidia-gl-450.

[image: Bug shown here]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Here is the solution that I used.

**Step 1**: Copy the python code and make it into an executable file and place it on your home folder

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os,signal
import time
a=1
while (a==1):
    try:   
        #iterating through each instance of the proess 
        process=os.popen('ps aux | grep "brave.com/brave/brave --type=gpu-process" | 
        grep -v grep')
        str=(process.read())
        length=0
        length=len(str)
        if (length==0):
            print("Process Teminated..")
            a=2
        else:
            for line in os.popen('ps aux | grep "brave.com/brave/brave --type=gpu-process" | grep -v grep'):  
                fields = line.split() 
                #extracting Process ID from the output 
                pid = int(fields[1])  
                res=fields[3]
                res=float(res)/100*7.69*1024 #7.69 is the amount of ram i have.... yours might vary.
                # terminating process  
                if(res>100):
                    print(f"pid={pid} res={res}")
                    os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGKILL)  
                    print("Process Successfully terminated") 
                time.sleep(6)
                length=0
      
    except: 
        print("Error Encountered while running script") 
        time.sleep(10)
```

**Step 2**: Create a shell script to launch both the applications at the same time

```
cd /usr/bin/;brave-browser-stable & brave=$!
sleep 2
cd /home/<your-username-here>/;./kill-gpu-brave & kill=$! #I named my  python execulable file kill-gpu-brave
wait $brave
wait $kill
```

**Step 3**: Make this an executable file with `chmod +x <filename>` and launch brave through this file.

Comment: For chrome the command will change. Please check your task manager. It will come under "--type=gpu-process"