# Display errors (pixelated areas) after Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, intel

Since I updated to Ubuntu 20.04 (using the regular Software Update, not a fresh install) I started seeing strange display glitches on my desktop. The background image has pixelated stripes and some symbols in menus and the desktop bar at the top are not displayed correctly:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm running on an Intel NUC Core i5 with Intel Iris Graphics 540 using driver `i915` (5.4.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload). I did not fiddle with driver settings at all nor installed any drivers that don't come out-of-the-box with Ubuntu 20.04.

Is this a known problem that I just couldn't find information about? I found Chrome browser related posts like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273399/problems-with-chrome-browser-after-suspending-the-computer-on-ubuntu-20-04), but they appear unrelated. With Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I did not have any such problem at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated!