# No tty for new 18.04

Tags: display-resolution, tty

I've just completed a fresh install of 18.04. An install of NVDIA drivers failed and now my resolution is 1024x768. I've attempted to go to a tty so I can install the drivers without the console running. However using CTl-ALT-F3 or F4 just bings me to a black screen with no prompt. I can get back to the GUI by using CTL-ALT-F2.

What can I do to get to a tty?

Comment: I had the problem only when nvidia driver was installed: [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-340/+bug/1811402)

Comment: Try rebooting into recovery mode? It's one of the options on the GRUB menu.

Answer (score 0):

It was the nvidia driver. Thanks Jamo. I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032357/how-to-switch-from-nvidia-to-nouveau-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04) guide to remove it and now I can access the tty consoles.