# Laptop (only) screen flickering in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, laptop, intel-graphics

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11hfHQ6IGwbHw76lqHOSU9t12NweliKAA/view?usp=sharing) you can see there's much internal screen flickering on this laptop. Previously, I had Ubuntu 18.10. The screen flickering was not too much, it was only occasional but in 18.04.3 it increases day by day. The problem is not in hardware because in the bootloader menu screen doesn't flicker.

I tried using both Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) and GeForce **940M**X/PCIe/SSE2 Graphics. Screen flickering while using Nvidia is more as compared to Intel.

I'm also using an external monitor which works totally fine without any flickering.

I couldn't find any concrete solution to solve this problem.

Driver info:

```
(base) prabhat@prabhat-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
 == /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
 modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000134Dsv0000103Csd0000820Cbc03sc02i00
 vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation 
 model    : GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
 driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
 driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - distro non-free recommended
 driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Also `nvidia-smi` is showing nvidia-driver-430

[Here](https://www.nvidia.in/Download/driverResults.aspx/150811/en-in) is the link to recomended 435.21 driver on nvidia website

Comment: Are you using NVIDIA's proprietary 367.27 drivers https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/104284/ or the Nouveau drivers https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032357/how-to-switch-from-nvidia-to-nouveau-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04 ? Please click [edit] and advise. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, please click [edit].

Comment: I'm using proprietary drivers. Driver Version: 430.26

Comment: Plz see updated info on drivers. I don't think I've wrong drivers.

Comment: You have chosen the driver for the 980, not what you have, the 980M. Please read the list for each driver, and you will see the one I linked to is for the 980 and 980M, whereas yours is 980 only. What you have now does not work as you like it, hence I researched, found a discrepancy, and suggest a solution available at no expense.