# Inspirion 7k temp low fan high - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dell, hardware, fan, temperature, 20.04

I've installed the last version of Ubuntu (20.04) and I have an issue with my fan : even if my CPU temp is low my fan is working at max speed :(

I use `sensors` to check temp and fan speed :

```
# sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +35.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +32.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +34.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +34.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +32.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +32.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +33.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
fan1:        4975 RPM
fan2:        5132 RPM

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          10.78 V  
curr1:         1.34 A  

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +32.0°C  

pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +35.0°C  

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)
```

I've tryed to reduce speed manualy using `i8k` :

```
# i8kfan 1 1
2 2
```

I can hear the fan slowing down and then speeding up again (1 or 2 seconds after).

Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The same issue here with a fresh installed `Ubuntu 20.04` but on an Asus Laptop.

I thought that it's a non-selected driver issue when I go to `Software & Updates` -> `Additional Drivers`. It was marked as `continue using a manually installed driver` and the others were disabled.

Than I followed this https://askubuntu.com/a/1032365/829928 instructions to select a driver:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices    # list drivers that are available to be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories
$ sudo apt install [xserver-xorg-video-nouveau]
```

I installed `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` for my system then `rebooting` solved the fan speed issue.

Maybe this method can work for your system as well.

***Edit:*** *The issue occurred again within a few days. Trying `$ ubuntu-drivers list` then `$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440` didn't work as well.*

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue on my DELL Inspiron 7591 running **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**. So I believe it should work on 20.04 as well.

What you did was correct using `i8kfan` but it stops quickly because the BIOS will take over the control of the fans.

So, I managed a workaround for this situation (thanks to the GitHub repo https://github.com/TomFreudenberg/dell-bios-fan-control) by overriding the BIOS control.

1. Clone the repo to your machine.
2. Run the `Makefile` (just type `make` in terminal in the directory of `Makefile`).
3. This will create an executable file `dell-bios-fan-control`.
4. You can use this file as shown in their GitHub Repo README (You need to pass `0` as argument to disable the BIOS control & then try running `i8kfan` like you did earlier).

This worked for me, I can't ensure the same to all cases.