# Ubuntu cannot turn back on after suspend

Tags: suspend, lenovo, 20.10

I have a Lenovo-Legion-Y530-15ICH laptop. Initially I had a dual boot system with Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10. After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.10 the problem appeared. Specifically, when I try to turn it on after suspension, a black screen appears with a dash on the upper left corner, that does not even blink and freezes there. It doesn't even show the log-in screen. It is totally unresponsive and every time I have to reboot it with the power button. I removed 20.10 and reinstalled it from scratch (along with windows 10) but nothing changed. In Ubuntu 20.04 I didn't have this problem.

In reply to Carles Mateo response, I checked if it hibernates but that should not be the case. I turn it on just some seconds after going to suspension and the problem appears every time. I checked also the memory allocation. I have 8G of RAM and 2G of Swap file. The swap space is not too large but I see that with SSD no more is needed.

I also attach the logs [here](https://pastebin.com/f1r86Xth). In line 508 a BIOS error appears. In line 1590 I think there is another error related to some SSD dependency.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem on my Acer Predator laptop with an Nvidia GTX1060 video card. If I waited a few minutes after it freezes an error message appeared from nvidia_modeset. Are you using the Nvidia video drivers?

You can resolve this issue by switching to the open source Nouveau driver:

[How to switch from nvidia to nouveau drivers on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032357/how-to-switch-from-nvidia-to-nouveau-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Update: The problem was occuring with version 450 of the Nvidia driver. Version 455 has just released. Updating to this new version also fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Lenovo-Legion-Y530 too and I had the same problem. So, I solved this problem as follows:

First, apparently this is about the nvidia-card-driver. My installed driver was nvidia-driver-450. I updated it to nvidia-driver-455 and the issue was gone. For installing the edge version of the driver you better add the nvidia repository first:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

Then run the command below to get the list of driver versions that are available:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

You'd better install the last version released. For me, the last version is nvidia-driver-455. So I run:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-455
```

Then reboot and check if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Many laptops hibernate after certain time suspended.
While suspended the computer keeps the info on memory, and use a small amount of energy, while hibernating it puts the contents of the memory into a file and completely powers off.
In Linux this dump of the memory is put on the Swap.
If you have 16 GB o RAM, you need at least 16 GB of Swap assuming you was using 0% of the swap.
Many people recommend to have a swap of double size of your RAM memory for that reason.
To know the memory and the swap in use execute:

```
free -h
```

Make sure your config is not to hibernate instead of suspend.

If you just suspend it, like closing the lid, if you open it back again after 10 seconds or 5 minutes (so making sure is just suspended), it works?.

If the fail is after suspend many things could be wrong, from old firmware, to the drivers of one device. We would need to see the logs to provide more information.

Do you see anything in:

```
/var/log/syslog
```

or

```
dmesg -T | less
```

Cheers.

Comment: Hibernating on a SSD is bad for the SSD: you will be writing the entire contents of all RAM everytime, making the SSD wear out faster.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. However I don't think it hibernates. I set it to suspend and immediately after the suspension I try to turn it on again, but doesn't work. I also checked the memory. I have 8gb of RAM and 2 gb swap memory. Swap it's not so much but I checked that SSD does not need more. Although, if you think this is relevant I could to allocate a bit more space.

Comment: Thanks for the update. No, you don't need more swap unless you open a lot of programs in need more memory. You have to look at "dmesg -T" and "less /var/log/syslog" for errors. If you press G in less you go to the end of the file were viewing. You can also "cat /var/log/syslog | grep panic" to look for kernel panics. Next time it hangs can you press CTRL + ALT + F1 to see if you go to Terminal (to check if it is x windows / video driver which is crashing). Cheers

Comment: I've tried CTRL+ ALT + F1 and like Magikarp's Splash...nothing happened.

Comment: You can try with CTRL + ALT + F2, F3, F4, F5 or F6. However it seems to have a kernel panic. Did you install special drivers for anything (graphics card, wifi...)?.

Comment: Nothing dramatically changed. The only thing is, that the dash on the upper left corner disappeared with CTRL+ALT+F2, I think. Also I didn't install any drivers.

Comment: Do you have another computer so you can check if the computer answers to ping?.

Comment: No response either.

Comment: Thanks for your time, though. :)

Comment: Can you disable every power saving feature in BIOS?. Sometime powersaving mode crash.

Comment: !(https://ibb.co/K94z9wb). As you can see, I couldn't find any power saving feature in BIOS  to disable.

Comment: @Adriaan *"Hibernating on a SSD is bad for the SSD..."* - No it isn't.  Yes, SSDs wear out differently than HDDs, but to avoid legitimate writes in effort to extend the life of an SSD is a fools errand.  Even if it's several GB of writes every reboot, it's not going to make an appreciable difference in the life of the disk.  SSDs are designed to withstand ~3000-6000 whole disk rewrites.  Even if you hibernated 8GB of RAM 5x times a day (extreme), it would take about **twenty years** to rewrite a 128GB SSD 4500 times.

Comment: @Nmath you can kill a SSD very easily. That's why there are the SSD SAS Enterprise grade, much more expensive, with a larger number of writes before failure. In general swap, specially if is being done often because there is memory starvation, will be bad for the life of the SSD. I recommend doing backups in spinning drives, and having them disconnected so the engine can last many more years.

Comment: @Carles. In an enterprise environment, drives are being written to *constantly*.  HDDs and SSDs alike are consumables in this context so of course there would be a demand for more durable SSDs.   But constant writes 24/7 is no comparison using hibernation, even if you do it every single day a few times a day.  By your logic, only store read-only data on SSDs, since writes are bad? Nonsense. That said, most advantages of hibernate on SSD v HDD are moot because there's little improvement since SSD random reads are so much faster than HDDs which benefits boot greatly.

Answer (score 0):

I spent days on this, the only way I managed to finally make it work was to reinstall linux from scratch and not confirm following option:

> Install third-party software for graphics and WiFi hardware and additional media formats

Once Ubuntu is installed, install NVIDIA drivers through

> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers

In my case (same laptop and Ubuntu 20.04) the problem would not fix if I install latest drivers (Nvidia-driver-470 & 460).