GeForce GT710 vs. Ubuntu 24.10
I installed Ubuntu 24.10 and the driver (NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02.run) of my graphics card (NVIDIA GK208B [GeForce GT 710]) does not want to install. The module: 'Software and update' does not find any driver in 'additional drivers'. The box 'proprietary drivers' is checked in 'Ubuntu Software'. When installing the driver from the terminal, this message (ERROR: You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before installing.) stops it.
What is this: Software Rendering (800x600)? How can I install this driver?
System Details Report
Report details

Date generated:    2024-10-12 18:42:41

Hardware Information: Hewlett-Packard HP Compaq

Hardware model:    6200 Pro SFF PC
Memory:            16.0 GB
Processor:         Intel Core i3-2100 × 4
Graphics:          Software Rendering
Disk capacity:     1.0 TB

Software Information

Firmware version:   J01 v02.15
OS name:            Ubuntu 24.10
OS build:           (null)
OS type:            64-bit
GNOME version:      47
Windowing system:   Wayland
Kernel version:     Linux 6.11.0-8-generic*


@A.L I suspect your comment should have been please write the question in English. ?

@Zeye oops, yes! Thanks for the notification.

Welcome, please write the question in English.

you have to stop the x server before installation, since you are using gnome I assume it is gdm.

ctrl + alt + f1, then log in
sudo systemctl stop gdm.service, should be correct
then you can install the driver with sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.256.02.run if the file has been made executable using chmod

it is best to install dkms before and let the driver build dkms modules, I had the problem that after every kernel update the driver did not work properly because the update did not automatically build the dkms modules. if you also want to use 32-bit libraries you have to install additional packages, I don't know exactly which ones but the installer will tell you if you try to install.
when you have finished the installation you can start the gdm again with
sudo systemctl start gdm.service
after that you should automatically jump to the desktop, otherwise ctrl + alt + F7
then you should be able to configure the Nvidia X Server as you wish in the settings
Hint
Before you try to install the driver from the Nvidia homepage yourself, you can try the command
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
to install the recommended Nvidia driver. In my case, it is not completely up to date but it is from the Ubuntu package sources and you can save yourself this whole process

Thank you for your answer but it dont works and the installation finished by error message who send me to /var/log/nvidia-installer.log . How can i send you this file ?

Were there any error messages? Can you explain more precisely what went wrong? I don't know if and how you could send it to me, Pastebin or something like that might be a possibility. I'm also new here

These old cards are no longer supported by the Nvidia drivers with the current kernels. (I have a GT730 in a test machine). You will have to use nouveau.
See, for example, Needing help installing NVIDIA legacy 340.xx driver for gt 730 on ubuntu 20.04

Are you absolutly sure that there is no way for use my GeForce GT 710 with ubuntu 24.10 ?

@user1973230 As my answer said, you should be able to use it with the nouveau driver. As far as the proprietary drivers go - this is a volunteer user site, it doesn't come with a guarantee. If you figure out a way, come back and post an answer.

sorry, explain me more about use nouveau, i am beginer

@user1973230 You can see which driver is in use by looking at the "additional drivers" tab in the Software & Updates application. It have a checked box beside something like "using X.org X server - Nouveau display driver" If it doesn't say that, you can tick the box beside this entry and hit Apply Changes. This driver works OK on my GT730 card.

Nothing appears in "additional drivers" tab in the Software & Updates application ?!? it's perhaps this the problem ?

but there is this mention "Graphics: Software Rendering" in System Details Report

@user1973230 I have not seen that. I found this Q&A https://askubuntu.com/q/1032357/243321

I found this ;
Runtime Tests
Firmware Updater Verification: Pass (Not Contaminated)
Linux Swap: ! Fail (Not Encrypted)
Linux Kernel Verification: ! Fail (Contaminated)
Linux Kernel Lockdown: ! Fail (Not Enabled)
